# convert Pareto r.v. to Log-Normal r.v.

Tags: probability

If $X$ is distributed Pareto, is it possible to define a variable to $Y=f(X)$ such that $Y$ is distributed Log-Normal? I tried several functions but failed to create something like $(\log Y)^2$ in the density.

Answer (score 1):

A double Pareto distribution can be generated by mixing a number of log-normal distributions.[Mitzenmacher](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.im/1109190964) shows that using a geometric distribution to randomly sample log-normal distributions can lead to a
distribution that is extremely similar to a double Pareto distribution.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is via the cumulative distribution functions and their inverses.

Suppose that $X$ has a Pareto distribution with parameters $x_{\min{}}$ and $\alpha$ and you want to use it to construct a log-normally distributed random variable $Y$ whose logarithm has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then you can use $$Y = f(X) = {\exp\left(\mu + \sigma \, \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\left(\dfrac{x_{\min{}}}{X}\right)^\alpha \right) \right)} $$   where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution